# Перекрытие ссылок на странице

Tags: html, css

Я создавал меню используя `HTML и CSS`. Но есть проблема. Когда я открываю эти файлы в браузере пункты меню перекрывают друг друга!
вот код самих файлов:

```css
.t1 {
  padding: 20px;
}

.t2 {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #383838;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.t3 {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #383838;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.t4 {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #383838;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.t5 {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #383838;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.t6 {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #383838;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.t7 {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #383838;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.t8 {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #383838;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.t9 {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #383838;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="t1">
  <a class="t2">пункт</a><br/>
  <a class="t3">пункт</a><br/>
  <a class="t4">пункт</a><br/>
  <a class="t5">пункт</a><br/>
  <a class="t6">пункт</a><br/>
  <a class="t7">пункт</a><br/>
  <a class="t8">пункт</a><br/>
  <a class="t9">пункт</a><br/>
</div>
```

Можете запустить этот код в своём браузере и вы поймёте о чём я говорю.Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

А почему вы не используете таблицу или список для постоений меню?

```css
ul li{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Menu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: когда я использую список, то рядом с пунктами появляются точки. Они портят весь вид картины.

Comment: list-style:none; 
Изучайте сss

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете тег ссылки для меню это не запрещается

Что бы ссылка переносилась на новую строку не надо городить кучу принудительных переносов а достаточно указать display:block;

У вас есть ошибка в том что вы пропустили важный аттрибут `href` и ни чего у вас не перекрывается

```css
a{
  display:block;
}
.t2,.t3,.t4,.t5,.t6,.t7,.t8,.t9 {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #383838;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="t1">
  <a class="t2" href="#">пункт</a>
  <a class="t3" href="#">пункт</a>
  <a class="t4" href="#">пункт</a>
  <a class="t5" href="#">пункт</a>
  <a class="t6" href="#">пункт</a>
  <a class="t7" href="#">пункт</a>
  <a class="t8" href="#">пункт</a>
  <a class="t9" href="#">пункт</a>
</div>
```

Что бы список `li` не ставил маркеры применяют list-style:none; вот таким образом

```css
li{
  list-style:none;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:20px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding:4px 50px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #383838;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">link4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">link4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">link4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">link4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">link4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">link4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">link4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">link4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">link4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Ну и стоит сократить padding так как он логически повторяется так как в моём примере

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Comment: @kekula  галочка и пальчик вверх